# give values to Chartjs

Tags: angular, typescript, chart.js

I have that code that gives me how many times each date occurs on the array of date:

```
let month = [];
let current;
let count = 0;
chartDates = chartDates.sort()

for (var i = 0; i < chartDates.length; i++) {
    month.push(chartDates[i].split('-')[1]);
    if (chartDates[i] != current) {
        if (count > 0) {
            console.log(current + ' times ' + count);
        }
        current = chartDates[i];
        count = 1;
    } else {
        count++;
    }
}
if (count > 0) {
    console.log(current + 'times ' + count);
}
```

Which gives me the following output:

```
2010-02-08 times 1
2010-02-11 times 1
2010-03-05 times 1
2010-03-08 times 1
2017-09-19 times 3
2017-12-26 times 1
```

I want to give those values to one barchart, using chart.js, were "labels" are the dates and "data" are "each time that date occurs.. I tried `year = [];` and then `year.push(current);` just to give me the date without repeating 
 equal dates inside each if, but no success..

How can i fix this problem?

my chart's:

```
var myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
               type: 'bar',
               data: {
                   labels: chartDates,
                   datasets: [{
                       label: month,
                       data: month,
                 .....
```

Comment: Where did you put your year.push(current)?

Comment: @RadonirinaMaminiaina my year.push(current) is inside for and if(charDates[i] != current) and inside if(count > 0), i'll post the code right away.. cause i think i found the solution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So i think i found the 95% of the solution for this problem.
I created a new array, in wish i push the current count of "occurs" so i have the pair (date - occurrences)
 - I now have a minor problem, the last date repeats!! and thats because  the last if(count > 0), but if i dont push the year, even i my console log gives the correct array of dates, my char only display 3 (?) Ill post the code and the print od the console log and chart!

**ts**

```
let month = [];
            let current;
            let count = 0;
            let year = [];
            let values = [];
           chartDates = chartDates.sort()

           for (var i = 0; i<chartDates.length; i++)
           {
               month.push(chartDates[i].split('-')[1]);
               if (chartDates[i] != current)
               {
                   if (count > 0)
                   {
                       //console.log(current + ' times ' + count);
                       values.push(count);
                   }
                   current = chartDates[i];
                   year.push(current);
                   count = 1;
               }
               else
                   {
                   count++;
                   }
           }
           if (count > 0)
           {
               //console.log(current + 'times ---' + count);
               //year.push(current);
               values.push(count);
           }


           console.log('datas: '+year+ ' contadores '+ count);
```

**chart inside ts**
var myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
               type: 'bar',
               data: {
                   labels: year,
                   datasets: [{
                       label: year,
                       data: values
    ...

Console log:

> datas:
>   2010-02-08,2010-02-11,2010-03-05,2010-03-08,2017-09-19,2017-12-26
>   contadores 1

the output:
[image]

FIX EDIT : if added year.push(current); it will fix, even if it displays last label repeated, but without any value.